# Mesos master setup, but home page does not return

Tags: mesos, mesosphere

I am just starting to try out Mesos.  I followed the instructions to get the master installed.  For now, I am using a single master (with 3 slaves).  I am installing on CentOS 6.5 - which is a Virtual Machine, terminal only.

The problem I am having is that if I navigate to port 5050 on that virtual machine from my desktop browser, I get no response.

However, from a terminal window if I do:

```
curl http://localhost:5050/
```

I get back an AngularJS page.  Which looks in part like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="mesos">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Mesos</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <link href="/static/css/bootstrap-3.0.3.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/static/css/mesos.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/static/ico/favicon.ico">
</head>

<body>
    <div data-ng-show="doneLoading" style="width: 75px; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center;">
```

If I ping the VM from my desktop, that works fine too.  However, if I use the curl command from my desktop (using the 'IP ADDRESS':5050), I get "couldn't connect to host"

Anyone with suggestions on what I might try to get this to work properly?

**New Information**

I ran netstat on the VM.  It gives me:

```
netstat -tapen | grep 5050
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5050                0.0.0.0:*          LISTEN      0        21589      2852/mesos-master
```

I suspect that is telling me what is wrong, but not sure how to fix it!  Also, running nmap from my desktop machine and scanning ports 5000-5100 on the VM shows all 101 ports closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what VM networking mode you're using. If the VM has an external IP (like 10.0.2.15), then you may be able to reach Mesos on `http://10.0.2.15:5050`, otherwise you may need to set up port forwarding or bridged/host-only networking modes. Check out this article on VM (virtualbox) networking for more info: https://blogs.oracle.com/fatbloke/entry/networking_in_virtualbox1

Comment: That Adam, but that is not the problem.  If I run Tomcat on the VM (which I do a LOT), I can access the box directly via http://machinename:8080/.   I can also ssh to the box via machine-name or ip address.  This is a mesos issue for some reason.

Comment: Ok, finally ran away from this.  I trashed the VM I was using above entirely, recreated a completely new one and re-did all the steps.  It is working and responding correctly now.  While I'll never know exactly what was causing the error condition, it wasn't a Mesos issue so I selected this as the correct answer!  Also, it likely took a LOT less time to regenerate a new VM that try to isolate the actual problem!